# SendMailAsync sending very slow using async and await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have an MVC controller which is called with an Ajax post to send an email. I have been trying to use the async/await pattern but am finding that the code below causes a significant delay on the SendMailAsync(email) method. Can anyone explain why this may be the case?

(Note, smtpClient is set in my webconfig of my UI project)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task TestMethod()
    {
        Workflow.Mailer rm = new Workflow.Mailer();
        await rm.TestEmailBasic();

    }

public async Task TestEmailBasic()
    {
        var email = new MailMessage("website@test.me", "sadsad@test.com", "Testing basic email", "Hello world");

        await SendEmailAsync(email);
    }

public async Task SendEmailAsync(MailMessage email)
    {
        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            email.Subject = "Async test";
            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By slow, how much time are we talking about exactly? What do you expect, and how does it behave?

Comment: How does it compare with not using async?  Could just be that your mail server takes a while to process messages from your webapp in an attempt to reduce spam.

Comment: Takes around 5 seconds. It takes a similar time without async too so you might be right. When I call the method with Ajax and catch the Success callback, I would have thought this would come back BEFORE the task finished though? At the moment it doesnt behave this way so it makes the UI feel unresponsive. Is there a way to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

As I explain on my blog, [async doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html). An `await` in an ASP.NET request "yields" to the ASP.NET threadpool, not to the browser. You can [return early](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) or [fire-and-forget](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) but those approaches can be dangerous because ASP.NET isn't designed for it.

Comment: Hmm I think some sort of queue is what I am after as I am not really waiting for a response as such. Fire and forget might be what I am after. THanks

Comment: Actually, if I wanted to return a value from my async method, say a string, can I do this whilst the smtpClient is doing its thing in the thread?

Comment: @Raj: If you use fire-and-forget, then you can return whatever you want. The response is sent and the HTTP request is considered complete. However, please note that fire-and-forget is very dangerous on ASP.NET; you should only use it if it's not critical to actually send the email.

Comment: So what in your opinion and experience is the best (and simples) method to achieve the most responsive UI in this case. Message queue sounds the best but seems like overkill for just this one feature?

Comment: @Raj: Depends on what the emails are used for. If they're critical (i.e., your product *needs* to send those emails in order to be functional), then a message queue is the only appropriate option. If they're nice-to-have (i.e., they're just notifications and your users have other ways of seeing the results), then you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: Cheers, so reading around this topic, Hangfire.io is mentioned quite a bit. Sounds like this may be the best way to handle what I need. Thanks

Comment: HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem worked out perfectly. Thank you @Stephen Cleary